# Find minimum and maximum values of a function

Tags: python, function, max, min

I have a function and I would like to find its maximum and minimum values. My function is this:

```
def function(x, y):
    exp = (math.pow(x, 2) + math.pow(y, 2)) * -1
    return math.exp(exp) * math.cos(x * y) * math.sin(x * y)
```

I have an interval for x [-1, 1] and y [-1, 1]. I would like to find a way, limited to this interval, to discover the max and min values of this function.

Comment: Are you really limited to just this function?  Or do you want to be able to do this for an arbitrary function?  If it's just this function, then you can find relative extrema by differentiating.

Comment: You should probably take a look here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html

Comment: Do you want close estimates or the exact floating point maximum?

Comment: Hi, @mgilson, this is a test function. It will may change.

Comment: @ShashankGupta, it could be close estimates. Thank you all.

Comment: @EmanueleBezzi, I have already looked at it. But I didn't figure out how to this with a function z = f(x,y), and not just y = f(x).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Using, for instance, `scipy`'s [`fmin`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html#scipy.optimize.fmin) (which contains an implementation of the Nelder-Mead algorithm), you can try this:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fmin
import math

def f(x):
    exp = (math.pow(x[0], 2) + math.pow(x[1], 2)) * -1
    return math.exp(exp) * math.cos(x[0] * x[1]) * math.sin(x[0] * x[1])

fmin(f,np.array([0,0]))
```

which yields the following output:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
     Current function value: -0.161198
     Iterations: 60
     Function evaluations: 113 
array([ 0.62665701, -0.62663095])
```

Please keep in mind that:

1) with `scipy` you need to convert your function into a function accepting an array (I showed how to do it in the example above);

2) `fmin` uses, like most of its pairs, an iterative algorithm, therefore you must provide a starting point (in my example, I provided `(0,0)`). You can provide different starting points to obtain different minima/maxima.

Comment: Awesome, but as we can just pass an start point, there is a way to limit the function in a range as I mentioned in my question or I could receive an output out of my range (this is what it seems to me)? Thanks for the attention.

Comment: You can use a method that supports variable bounding, like `fmin_tnc` (it is used like this: `fmin_tnc(f,np.array([0.5,-0.5]), approx_grad=True, bounds=[(-1,1),(-1,1)])`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is something which gives fairly close estimates (not exact).

```
import math
import random
import sys

def function(x, y):
    exp = (math.pow(x, 2) + math.pow(y, 2)) * -1
    return math.exp(exp) * math.cos(x * y) * math.sin(x * y)

max_func = - sys.maxint - 1
min_func = sys.maxint
maximal_x, maximal_y = None, None
minimal_x, minimal_y = None, None

for i in xrange(1000000):
    randx = random.random()*2 - 1
    randy = random.random()*2 - 1
    result = function(randx, randy)
    max_func = max(max_func, result)
    if max_func == result:
        maximal_x, maximal_y = randx, randy
    min_func = min(min_func, result)
    if min_func == result:
        minimal_x, minimal_y = randx, randy

print "Maximal (x, y):", (maximal_x, maximal_y)
print "Max func value:", max_func, '\n'
print "Minimal (x, y):", (minimal_x, minimal_y)
print "Min func value:", min_func
```