# Find the values of variables at which minimize of the maximum of a function happens?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, scipy, statistics

I am trying to write a python code to find the value of say `x, y` at which maximum of certain functions say `f_1(x,y)` and `f_2(x,y)` gets minimized.

Currently, I am doing the same in Mathematica but it is very slow due to large datasets. The syntax I am using in Mathematica is:

```
Minimize[Max[ f1[x,y], f2[x,y] ], {x,y} ]
```

Any comments or suggestions will be highly appreciated!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find minimum and maximum values of a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18965195/find-minimum-and-maximum-values-of-a-function)

Comment: This isn't a very clear question. Are you trying to minimize

```
import numpy as np

def g(x, y):
    f1 = f_1(x, y)
    f2 = f_2(x, y)
    return np.max(f1, f2)
```